# Collection of abandoned accounts

Tags: support

Mrs. Chatherine, your community manager, collected some of the found previous accounts and merged them. Thought that she might busy in many things, here as well shared if wishing to assist her or those interested in such.

If coming across one, my person will mention it here, said that it is wished to easier find relate question and answers, so those able could act how they wish to:

7500, 7555, 14343, 14862, 14559, 12996, 11479, 12858, 12845, 14131, 11958, 14895.

(The support-tag is used since to such as "announcing", "comment" tag is avaliable. Not to be seen as asking for or even demand.)

*(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks, entertainment but as means to escape this wheel)*

Comment: There seem to be others, too, e.g. 14895. Perhaps I'm unable to search for them since they're unregistered.

Comment: This gives a 404 error, so not sure if previous related. The others mentioned have been come across on the site, not by searches.

Comment: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/14895/samana-johann

Comment: Another is https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/14937/samana-johann

Answer (score 0):

Thank you (and, yes, [support](/questions/tagged/support) was the right tag for this topic).

---

There were many accounts, and I'm not sure which accounts the CM used to merge into the current account i.e. 11235 -- but I'm pretty sure that did include 7500 -- i.e. that any content posted under 7500 is already merged into the current 11235 account.

If there are other accounts you'd like to have merged but which haven't been merged yet -- 7555 for example -- then I think you can initiate that process:

- Click on [the Contact form](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/contact)
- Select "I need to merge user profiles" as the topic in reply to "What can we help you with?"

SE has software tools to merge account, tools which a site moderator like me can't access -- so I can't normally help with this, instead it's initiated by the user and that Contact form.

In this case I can also ping the CM informally, to notify her that you posted here.

Comment: Sadhu for effort. What ever may be wished.

Answer (score 0):

Please see "[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)".

At this time of writing, it says:

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please
> sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I
> need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange
> Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can
> confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email
> address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.